# Design time slider

Tags: html, reactjs

I wish to add this design as a time slider in my dashboard.

Has anyone ever designed this using React, HTML? Any help is appreciated.

[image: Snapshot of Time slider]

Comment: I think your question needs to be more specific: are you trying to achieve this feature by using React? You should give more details how you want the user to interact with your time slider component. For example, click on any of the year triggers will refresh of the background map or something so we can give you some suggestions.

Comment: @MattYao Yes I am trying to achieve this using React. The way users would interact maybe either click/hover/slide on any of the year triggers which would a)increase/decrease the size of circles, width of lines depending on some attributes for that particular year b) also add and remove features on map based on year.

Answer (score 0):

If those circles, lines are based on your returned json data, it is quite straightforward with React / Redux. You can follow the steps:

1. You need to add event listeners on your timeline either click or mouseover
2. Define the state variable mapData in the constructor
3. trigger the event and retrieve different data via http request
4. make sure you call setState() with the new data and bind them into your state variables
5. Bind the state variable into the render() elements and you will see the change.

Hopefully it can help you out.

Comment: Thanks for the info Matt but I am looking in terms of design for the slider and not the functionality for now.